# How to get orders shipping method full name via REST API?

Tags: shipping, rest-api

The order object from `V1/orders/{$id}` only contains the shipping methods short name, not the full (e.g. localized) name. When using an extension like matrixrate, the shipping method only contains something like `matrixrate_matrixrate_123` which is completely useless.

Is there any way the get the full name via REST?

Answer (score 0):

The full shipping method name is found in the `shipping_description` field on the order object.